# Appium Java: checkbox element is never clicked iOS

Tags: selenium, appium, xcuitest

I am trying to check the element but is never clicked

```
WebElement checkBox = driver.findElementByXPath("//XCUIElementTypeOther[@name=\"checkTerms\"]");

System.out.println(checkBox.getAttribute("enabled"));

checkBox.click();
```

it prints true but nothing happens

Appium 1.11.1

appium java-client 7.0.0

selenium-java 3.141.59

I am using this pod https://cocoapods.org/pods/M13Checkbox to show checkboxes

[image]

If I click on tap in the right panel it works as expected.

**Edit:** I have to click it after filling user/password and I can't hide the keyboard after password (it's numeric keyboard) getting WebDriverException but it's working one time hiding it after user textfield.

**Edit2:** No matter keyboard is shown checkbox is never tapped.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: I don't have any error but when I check the element with appium desktop enabled is always true and I don't see any attribute "checked"

Comment: The enabled property is not going to change when you click/tap the element.  What happens to the other properties when you click the tap button on the viewer?  Do any of them change value?  Normally, I would check for a value attribute, but it's not clear from your screenshot whether or not that's what to do.  I work with Android, not IOS, so mine looks a bit different.

Comment: were you able to click it using appium desktop inspector?  Select the element and try to click **tap** button in the appium desktop inspector.

Comment: @SubanDhyako I am able to tap it on appium desktop an I can record the tap action giving me  -- MobileElement el1 = (MobileElement) driver.findElementByAccessibilityId("checkTerms");
  el1.click(); -- but never works on code. appium server 1.11.1 desktop 1.10.0

 Bill nothing changes and attribute value is never shown in desktop and I can't get it trough code

Comment: Some times what happens is the appium script try to interact with the element that is  not currently present but will be present after certain seconds, specially when navigating from one screen to other screen. In such case you can use ExplicitWait to wait for certain times until the element is available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it scrolling down to the next element to the checkbox. for some reason even if it was appearing on the screen the view couldn't tap the element so it worked scrolling down to password textfield and then click into the checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveTo(checkbox);
action.click();
action.perform();
```

Comment: it's also not working and I don't understand why...
Maybe because checkbox is from a pod https://cocoapods.org/pods/M13Checkbox?

Comment: can you add `System.out.println(checkBox.getAttribute("name"));` just want to make sure you are pointing to the right element

Comment: it prints "checkTerms"

Comment: Ok. 1 more check. `MobileElement element = (MobileElement) driver.findElementByXPath("//XCUIElementTypeOther[@name=\"checkTerms\"]");
boolean isSelected = element.isSelected();`, try this and see what's the outcome.

Comment: Sorry, try this `tap` option. `Point checkLocation = checkbox.getLocation();
        driver.tap(1, checkLocation.getX()+10, checkLocation.getY()+10, 1);`

Comment: I can't do this way with my driver but I tried. new TouchAction((MobileDriver) driver).tap(new TapOptions().withPosition(new PointOption().point(checkLocation.getX()+10, checkLocation.getY()+10))).perform();

getting the following error https://justpaste.it/edit/27246849/5a4d78c299a81685